# Can I initialize variables using a for loop with a counter?

Tags: php

I'm trying to initialize iterations of variables that i'm sending to my server-side script. I don't want to enter each of them individually so I am wondering if what I have is valid syntax or if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
for($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++){
  $itemNumber.$i = $_POST['title'.$i];
  $itemType.$i = $_POST['type'.$i];
  $itemDescription.$i = $_POST['description'.$i];
  $itemAmount.$i = $_POST['amount'.$i];
  $itemComments.$i = $_POST['comments'.$i];
}
```

My expected output is:

`$itemNumber1 = $_POST['title1'];`

`$itemType1 = $_POST['type1'];`

`...`
after the first iteration and etc.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? I can almost guarentee there is a better way

Comment: Have you read about [arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using PHP's [Curly Brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) (Also called Complex Syntax)

```
for($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++){
    ${"itemNumber$i"} = $_POST["title$i"];
    ${"itemType$i"} = $_POST["type$i"];
    ${"itemDescription$i"} = $_POST["description$i"];
    ${"itemAmount$i"} = $_POST["amount$i"];
    ${"itemComments$i"} = $_POST["comments$i"];
}
```

But you really probably shouldn't, there is probably a much much better way to handle what you are trying to do.